# Using NServiceBus, how to check if the bus is ready?

Tags: nservicebus

If I try to send a message (using `bus.Send<SomeCommand>(...)` for example), and the endpoint is not available for some reason (perhaps it has not been set up yet), I get an exception similar to the following

> *The destination queue 'myqueue@mycomputer' could not be found. You may
>   have misconfigured the destination for this kind of message
>   (MyCommands.SomeCommand) in the MessageEndpointMappings of the
>   UnicastBusConfig section in your configuration file. It may also be
>   the case that the given queue just hasn't been created yet, or has
>   been deleted.*

I would like to avoid this by checking ahead of time (on app startup) that the bus is ready and the endpoint is reachable.

Short of catching exceptions on every bus.Send, is there some other way to determine the health of the bus?  I'm looking for something like `bus.IsReady()` but I can't find it.

Comment: What profile are you running with?

Comment: And which version of NServiceBus are you using?

Comment: That exception will only occur if the client is on the same machine as the server. There is no way to know if the queue exists if the server is on a remote machine so there isn't really anything you can do to figure out if the receiving endpoint is ok.

Comment: And what if you're sending to more than one endpoint and one of them is down? In short it doesn't makes sense to check the state of other endpoints.

Comment: NSB 3.2.8.  The receiving bus is running the NSB Host with the Integration profile.  The sender is a web application on the same server, but I suppose in production they could be on different machines.  Perhaps I should just send a dummy message in a try/catch block and do nothing in the handler?  Perhaps run it periodically to act as a heartbeat?  I think that would work, just wasn't sure if it's a good approach or if something else is already built in to handle this.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, why can't I store the messages on a local queue and then forward them to the remote queue when it comes online? Is anything like this built in to NSB already?  One of the main reasons we're using NSB is to separate the front and back ends, so I would hope the front end could still operate if the back end was offline.

Comment: >Thinking about it some more, why can't I store the messages on a >local queue and then forward them to the remote queue when it comes >online? Is anything like this built in to NSB already?  => this is exactly what the store and forward capabilities of MSMQ will do for you automatically. Configure your web app to send to a non existing server and take a look at the "outgoing queues" in msmq